# SharePoint on internet

Tags: 2013, internet

Is it safe to host my website portal.mycompany.com on internet. It will have a maximum of 5 pages and it will be available to everyone. Is it wise to do this? I am not sure about the security impact it will have. We have a farm solution installed and hosted in our servers. Is SharePoint safe enough to connect it to World wide web ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many options in exposing a SharePoint site to the Internet. You could set up a dedicated server in your DMZ totally disconnected from the LAN and host your website there. Or you could go with a reverse proxy-topology. Check the following for info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199(v=office.15).aspx

Next there are some security hardening guidelines that you should take, not limited to Internet-scenario's. More on this:

[Security planning for SharePoint 2013 farms](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377941(v=office.15).aspx)

[Plan security hardening for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262849(v=office.15).aspx)

[SharePoint Security: Server Hardening](http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2010/sharepoint-security-server-hardening)

And finally, make sure to minimize the attack surface by avoiding installing a lot of different components on this server. There is an Analyzer tool as well but I have not tried it yet: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24487

Answer (score 1):

How do you mean "Is SharePoint safe enough"? Many people build public websites on SharePoint, and SharePoint in Office 365 is "on internet". I should say it is up to you if you are comfortable of storing that information outside of your own network.

Otherwise you could use TMG or similar for making sure people have to sign in to reach your content

Answer (score 0):

sharepoint is safe enough, I tried it to build my website [www.broadbandchandigarh.info](http://www.broadbandchandigarh.info) and it is a successful method.